# Arriba, Abajo al Centro pa Dentro

Tags: diferencias-regionales, etimología

"Arriba. abajo, al centro y adentro" o "pa dentro" Tengo mucha curiosidad sobre esa forma de brindar. En México se usa en contextos muy reducidos vinculados con exceso alcohol o en forma de juego; en Argentina y Uruguay en cambio está más extendido y puede usarse en más situaciones como en familia y con amigos principalmente con vino la situación es parecida en España. Podrían decirme ¿en qué otros países se utiliza y cuál es el origen?

Comment: Esa frase para mi es internacional, se usa en muchas cosas y lo más famoso es por el tequila. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNQWx2Rp3LU y se ven que estos no son latinos

Comment: Here's a little song for ya'll..!!! https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_sGU1kkBQcY&sns=fb![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJQlZ.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Esta fórmula popular es una parodia del hecho de santiguarse, igual que otros brindis populares (*proa, popa, babor y estribor, ¡rumbo a la bodega!*). En cuanto a su extensión geográfica, creo que necesitaremos que diversos hablantes nativos nos digan si es popular en su país o no. Aquí, en España, es bastante conocida. Aparecía en la película *Two Much*, donde era la favorita del personaje interpretado por Antonio Banderas, un español que vivía en Miami; pero ya era popular antes.

Answer (score 2):

En España, es un dicho que conservado su popularidad a lo largo del tiempo en parte gracias a los tunos:

> "La Tuna emplea dentro de una larga tradición, diversos 
>      brindis, algunos de los cuales utilizan elementos litúrgicos, 
>      o se basan en frases tomadas del canon de misa y que han sido 
>      heredados de las viejas formas goliárdicas, o de los clérigos 
>      vagantes, es decir, de los primeros escolares universitarios 
>      europeos de los siglos XII y XIII. "

(http://www.tunaceu.com/Cancionero/Brindis/Brindis.htm)

Algunas veces se utiliza se compara con el inglés:

> "Over the lips, over the gums, look out stomach, here it comes."

Answer (score -3):

El origen podria estar en la popular serie de tv, barrio sesamo, en la cual uno de sus personajes, Super Coco, utilizaba esta formula de arribaaa, abajooo... y los jovenes aqctuales rememoran ese momento haciendo con ello un homenaje a SuperCoco, para que veas Maricruz como eso eh azin

Comment: ¿Usted tiene una referencia para apoyar esta respuesta?